# Do we loose our Github earned badge if we leave the organisation where we have earned that badge?

Tags: github, badge, namespace-organisation

I've earned a few badges by contributing to a private organization. What if we leave that organization, will we lose that badge in the GitHub profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends. Your contributions and badges will stay as long as the email address associated with them remains on your account. If you are planning to change your email or delete the account then you will probably lose them.

This article might be helpful:
[Don't lose your GitHub contributions when you leave an organization](https://vikrantbhat.hashnode.dev/dont-lose-your-github-contributions-when-you-leave-an-organization)

Also I suggest that your read this too:
[GitHub Docs - Best practices for leaving your company](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/best-practices-for-leaving-your-company)